# Visa type if going to Hong Kong for training

Tags: visas, hong-kong

What is the visa type required for going to Hong Kong to attend 4 day training? Can we do the pre-registration (if we are eligible) and visit Hong Kong for training?

Training is about Elasticsearch organized by Elasticsearch company. And I am Indian.

Comment: Can you add information about the training (type/reason), done by whom (university, private company, etc). and your nationality? That will help get a response.

Comment: @Dorothy updated my query with the required details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an Indian national, you are [allowed entry](http://www.immd.gov.hk/eng/services/visas/visit-transit/visit-visa-entry-permit.html) visa free to visit for a period not exceeding 14 days. However, pre-arrival registration is required, as you note.

The [Immigration Department](http://www.immd.gov.hk/eng/faq/visit-transit.html) states that nationals who are allowed to enter Hong Kong without a visa may do so for tourism or business-related purposes, the latter limited to:

> [C]oncluding contracts or submitting tenders, examining or supervising the installation/packaging of goods or equipment, participating in exhibitions or trade fairs (except selling goods or supplying services direct to the general public, or constructing exhibition booths), settling compensation or other civil proceedings, participating in product orientation, and attending short-term seminars or other business meetings.

Your 4-day training would appear to come under participation in product orientation, short-term seminar or other business meeting.

> Indian nationals are required to apply for and successfully complete pre-arrival registration (PAR) online before they can visit the HKSAR visa free. Please click [here](http://www.immd.gov.hk/eng/services/visas/pre-arrival_registration_for_indian_nationals.html) for details of PAR.

Comment: wow, amazing. I can't thank more. Will read the reply in detail with the links.

Comment: Ok as mentioned here pre-registration was enough to get an entry!!!